# Further Group by Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Current SQL Statement:

```
SELECT count(installUserID) as userCount
  FROM installUsers
  group by installationID
```

Current output:

```
userCount
4
2
1
1
1
2
4
1
3
1
```

I am trying to count the number of times the `userCount` is 1, as well as 2, etc...

Example of desired output:

```
userCount = 1, 5 times
userCount = 2, 2 times
userCount = 3, 1 times
userCount = 4, 2 times
```

I've looked around the internet and I am thinking there is something I can do with aggregate functions, perhaps with `grouping`, but I am still unclear of how to go about implementing this with pure sql.

Comment: You almost have it `SELECT installUserID, count(installUserID) as userCount
  FROM installUsers
  group by installationID`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want a count of the counts. To do this you can use an outer select:

```
SELECT userCount, COUNT(*) AS userCountcount
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(installUserID) as userCount
    FROM installUsers
    GROUP BY installationID
) AS T1
GROUP BY userCount
ORDER BY userCount
```

Comment: Why would you need an inner select statement for this?

Comment: Because a) the `GROUP BY` is different and b) you can't nest aggregate functions. I didn't say that you *need* an inner select - you *can* use an inner select... or you can use a CTE. It doesn't make a huge difference.

Comment: The CTE is not necessary, simply COUNT the column and GROUP by the same column.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use a CTE.  Maybe over kill for this but comes in mighty handy.

```
WITH count_cte(usercount)
AS
(
  SELECT COUNT(installUserID) AS userCount
  FROM installUsers
  GROUP BY installationID
)

SELECT  usercount  ,COUNT(usercount) AS times  FROM count_cte GROUP BY usercount
```